# Efficient resampling for the sum of specific values in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = c("dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "fish", "fish", "fish", "squid", "squid", "squid"),
    y = c(10, 11, 6, 3, 4, 5, 5, 9, 14, 33, 16)
)
```

I want to iterate through the data and grab one value for each animal in some "inclusion/filter" list and then sum them together.

For instance, maybe I just care about dog, cat, and fish.

```
animals <- c("dog", "cat", "fish")
```

In resample 1, I could get 10, 4, 9 (sum = 23) and in resample 2 I could get 6, 3, 5 (sum = 14).

I just whipped up a really janky replicate/for function that leans on `dplyr`, but it seems super inefficient:

```
ani_samp <- function(animals){

    total <- 0
    for (i in animals) {

        v <- df %>% 
            filter(x == i) %>% 
            sample_n(1) %>% 
            select(y) %>% 
            as.numeric()

        total <- total + v
    }
    return(total)
}

replicate(1000,ani_samp(animals))
```

How might I improve this resampling/pseudo-bootstrap code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this much better (don't have time for benchmarks), but you could avoid the double loop here. You could first filter by `animals` (and hence work on a subset) and then sample `n` samples only once from each group. If you like `dplyr`, here's a possible `dplyr/tidyr` version

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

ani_samp <- function(animals, n){
  df %>%
    filter(x %in% animals) %>% # Work on a subset
    group_by(x) %>%
    sample_n(n, replace = TRUE) %>% # sample only once per each group
    group_by(x) %>%
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>% # Create an index for rowSums
    spread(x, y) %>% # Convert to wide format for rowSums
    mutate(res = rowSums(.[-1])) %>% # Sum everything at once
    .$res # You don't need this if you want a data.frame result instead
} 

set.seed(123) # For reproducible output
ani_samp(animals, 10)
# [1] 18 24 14 24 19 18 19 19 19 14
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is:

```
set.seed(123) ## for reproducibility
n <- 1000 ## number of samples for each animal
samps <- do.call(cbind, lapply(animals, function(x) {sample(df$y[df$x == x], n, replace=TRUE)}))
head(samps, 10)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]   10    3    5
## [2,]    6    4    5
## [3,]   11    3    5
## [4,]    6    4    5
## [5,]    6    4    5
## [6,]   10    3    5
## [7,]   11    4    5
## [8,]    6    3    5
## [9,]   11    3    5
##[10,]   11    3    5
sum <- as.vector(samps %*% rep(1,length(animals)))
head(sum, 10)
##[1] 18 15 19 15 15 18 20 14 19 19
```

Here, we use `lapply` to loop over the `animals` and generate 1000 samples of `df$y` for which `df$x` matches the animal using `sample` with replacement. Then, we `cbind` the results together so that each row of `samp` is a sampling of `animals`. The last line is just row sums using matrix multiply.

`system.time` for this is almost instantaneous for 1000 samples of each `animal`:

```
n <- 1000 ## number of samples for each animal
system.time(as.vector(do.call(cbind, lapply(animals, function(x) {sample(df$y[df$x == x], n, replace=TRUE)})) %*% rep(1,length(animals))))
##   user  system elapsed 
##  0.001   0.000   0.001
```

This should also scale well with number of samples `n`.